# Generating a table of solutions for an equation

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I am trying to solve numerically an equation and generate some results. I use the following code

```
u[c_] := (c^(1 - σ) - 1)/(1 - σ)
f[s_] := g s (1 - s/sbar1)
h[s_] := (2 hbar)/(1 + Exp[η (s/sbar - 1)])
co[a_] := ϕ (a^2)/2
ψ[k_] := wbar (ω + (1 - ω) Exp[-γ k])
```

The equation I try to solve is the following

```
adap[k_, s_] := (ρ + δ) u'[f[s] - priceadap δ k] co'[δ k] + ψ'[k] h[s]
```

I have the following constant parameter set

```
paramFinal2 = {σ -> 1.7, ρ -> 0.025, g -> 0.05, sbar -> 10, η -> 11, hbar -> 0.5,  priceadap -> 0.0006, γ -> 0.6, χ -> 1000, ϕ -> 0.05, ω -> 0.35, β -> 0.8, δ -> 0.065, sbar1 -> 10, wbar -> 1000};
```

So, for different values of $s$, I try to generate the corresponding values of $k$.

For this, I use the following code

```
tmax1 = 10;
solK[i_] := Solve[adap[k, i] == 0 /. paramFinal2, k];
Table[solK[i], {i, 1, tmax1}];
```

Unfortunately, this does not give any result. Mathematica is always on mode "Running...".

P.S I am using Mathematica 9.0

Answer (score 1):

I always find it a good idea to plot the functions you are investigating.  Thus

```
tmax1 = 10;
Column@Table[
  Plot[Evaluate[adap[k, i] /. paramFinal2], {k, 0, 20}], {i, 1 tmax1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

They all look fine except for the last one. The zero is at about k = 10 for most of the functions.
The equation is not a polynomial and thus may not be solvable using Solve. I don't know what range of equations Solve can deal with but some functions are just too complicated. The solution for this is to use FindRoot.

```
rts = Table[
  FindRoot[adap[k, i] /. paramFinal2, {k, 10}], {i, 1, tmax1}]
```

which gives

```
{{k -> 10.7363}, {k -> 12.1674}, {k -> 12.8497}, {k -> 13.185}, {k -> 
   13.2841}, {k -> 13.169}, {k -> 12.797}, {k -> 12.0139}, {k -> 
   10.3238}, {k -> 3.43075*10^39 - 3.28305*10^36 I}}
```

The last root is clearly wrong and is complex which gives us a clue. If we do

```
adap[k, 10] /. paramFinal2 /. k -> 1
```

We get

```
5269.92 + 7400.72 I
```

So this looks like a complex function. Thus

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[adap[k, 10] /. paramFinal2]], {k, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This suggests that you might not have a real root for this case.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Neither `Solve` nor `NSolve` will handle your equation. As Hugh has shown, you can use `FindRoot`. You could also use `FindInstance` as follows.

```
solK[i_] := FindInstance[adap[k, i] == 0 /. paramFinal2, k, Reals]
With[{tmax1 = 10}, Flatten @ Table[solK[i], {i, tmax1}]][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> {10.7363, 12.1674, 12.8497, 13.185, 13.2841, 13.169, 12.797, 12.0139, 10.3238}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

one approach here is to use `ContourPlot`

```
p = ContourPlot[(adap[k, s] /. paramFinal2) == 0, {s, 0, 10}, 
  {k, 0, 30}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

interpolate the curve and extract specific values:

```
g = Interpolation[First@Cases[Normal@p, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]];
Table[{s, g[s]}, {s, 9}]
```

> {{1, 10.7315}, {2, 12.1675}, {3, 12.8475}, {4, 13.1713}, {5, 
>     13.2854}, {6, 13.1591}, {7, 12.7972}, {8, 12.0124}, {9, 10.3233}}

note `ContourPlot` only finds points to adequate precison for plotting purposes. If you need better precision use as initial guesses for `FindRoot`:

```
Table[{s, k /. FindRoot[adap[k, s] /. paramFinal2, {k, g[s]}]},
 {s,9}]
```

> {{1, 10.7363}, {2, 12.1674}, {3, 12.8497}, {4, 13.185}, {5, 
>     13.2841}, {6, 13.169}, {7, 12.797}, {8, 12.0139}, {9, 10.3238}}